# How do I take a message to another player in Animal Crossing?

Tags: animal-crossing-city-folk

From time to time, a neighbor will ask me to take a message to another player in my Animal Crossing: City Folk game:

> I have a message I want you to take to him.

When I accept the mission, the neighbor will say something like:

> OK then, would you please tell *<name>* that I want to talk to him about "**wall designs**"?

Where 'wall designs' changes to whatever it is the neighbor wants to talk about.

I can't seem to figure out how to pass this message along.  I've tried sending a letter to the other player that includes the key word, but I've never received any kind of acknowledgment for my efforts.

How exactly does my neighbor want me to pass on this message, and what is the reward (if any) for doing so?

Comment: I thought you just talked to that character and it was in a new dialog tree option. It's been a while so I'm not certain though, I may be thinking of a different AC game

Comment: Another player or another townie?

Comment: Another *player*, so yeah it's not possible to just go talk to the intended recipient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person that the villager wants to talk to has to literally go and talk to the villager. Then you'll just type in what they wanted to talk about when the keyboard comes up.

Answer (score 1):

You have to log on to that account, go find the villager who asked you to deliver the message, then talk to them.  They'll ask if you if you heard the message, you'll say yes.  Then, type in the exact words he used.  He'll most likely give you a wallpaper.  Then, log back on to your original account and go talk to him again.  He'll give your original character a reward as well.

My villager, Mott asked me to tell Andrea "he wants to speak to her about wall decor".  I tried absolutely everything I could think of, and that's what I found worked.  I logged on to Andrea's account and spoke to him.  He gave her a Lovely Wall (I believe) and me an Exotic Wall.  It's one of the more complicated quests, but you get two prizes, so it's worth it.